# Reading and Manipulating HTML inside XML CDATA

Tags: c#, xml, cdata

When I grab HTML from an XML CDATA section, manipulate it (in my case, perform C# string methods on the text within the CDATA section), and then display the edited version... it automatically comments out my first HTML tag:

```
<![CDATA[ <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p> ]]>
```

converts to this on the page:

```
<!--[CDATA[ <p--> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... ]]>
```

which breaks the styling for that first paragraph and renders the closing CDATA tag after the content.

How do I fix this?

**EDIT:**
I couldn't find anything about this, so I tried a few things for poos and giggles, and this worked:

```
<![CDATA]> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p> </]]>
```

which converted to this on the page:

```
<!--[CDATA]--> <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p> <!--]]-->
```

However... I'm not sure if this will affect my page in a negative way?

Is there another way?

Comment: How do you convert it - let's see your code

Comment: How do you "grab HTML"? How do you "manipulate it"? How do you "display it"? And what is "it" that automatically comments out your first HTML tag?

Comment: first I create an object with a property Content that holds the InnerXml of the node that contains the CDATA HTML. Then I manipulate the content by finding image placeholders and replacing them with html elements (images with captions). I use the IndexOf, Remove, and Insert methods to find, remove, and replace the content.

Comment: It seems to be an issue between XmlNode.InnerXml and CDATA. When I use InnerText and CDATA... everything works fine. I don't have to add tag markup to the CDATA tags.

Comment: It also works if I simply use XmlNode.InnerXml and omit the CDATA tags altogether. I must be a rookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `XmlNode.InnerXml` on an XML element that contains CDATA... it comments out the first element.

Use `XmlNode.InnerText` and the CDATA will work.

If you *must* use InnerXml... you can omit the CDATA tags and it will also work.

If you need **both** InnerXml and CDATA, I don't have an answer... or a scenario where the two would be used together